# why does @Service not create bean

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have this class

```
@Service("customUserDetailsService")
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService { ....}
```

and im trying to make this work

security XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.carlosocortina.paidosSimple,com.carlosocortina.paidosSimple.dao,com.carlosocortina.paidosSimple.service"/>

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/sec/moderation.html" access="ROLE_ASISTENTE" />  
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="ROLE_DOCTOR" />   
        <form-login login-page="/user-login.html" 
            default-target-url="/success-login.html" 
            authentication-failure-url="/error-login.html" />  
        <logout logout-success-url="/index.html" />
    </http>  

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">  
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService" />
    </authentication-manager>  

</beans:beans>
```

But i keep getting this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0' while setting constructor argument with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'customUserDetailsService' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'customUserDetailsService' is defined
```

in short:  No bean named 'customUserDetailsService' is defined

and i dont know why, can anyone give me and advice.

addiontal info

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml,/WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Spring Security Configuration -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

try add `@Configurable` to your service

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the package for CustomUserDetailsService did not match your component scanning declaration:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.carlosocortina.paidosSimple,com.carlosocortina.paidosSimple.dao,com.carlosocortina.paidosSimple.service"/>
```

Or maybe the `@Service("customUserDetailsService")` syntax does not set the bean id, but the bean name instead.

If these both are not the cause, then probably Spring is just unable to refer to a bean that is yet to be scanned (a bit sad if this is the case).

As an alternative you can just take off the `@Service` annotation from CustomUserDetailsService and declare your bean manually on the xml, eg:

```
<bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="...">
```

Comment: i just tried this but I'm not very versatile at spring yet, and i tried declaring the beans that customUserDetailsService need but i got to SessionFactory and i dont know if its the same Session factory used for the transaction manager, if its i cant call it because it belongs to the servlet-contex.xml

Answer (score 0):

It is because the `servlet-context.xml` is placed inside the dispatcher servlet. Since dispatcher servlet is child of parent context, the parent context does not have the dependencies of child, So if you put the `servlet-context.xml` inside `context` param, and you must have the `appServlet-servlet.xml` inside the `init` param it will work fine.